# Python: conversion of a iterated assignment with an atomic assignment using numpy is not working when matrix height > 256

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, numpy, matrix

I'm working using **numpy 1.6.2** and **python 2.7**.
Given an `N x M x D` matrix `A` and a matrix `I` that contains a list of indices.
I have to fill a zeros matrix `ACopy` with the sum of element of `A` according to the indeces found in `I` (see code).

Here is my code:

```
ACopy = zeros(A.shape)
for j in xrange(0, size(A, 0)):
  i = I[j]
  ACopy[j, i, :] = A[j, i, :] + A[j, i + 1, :]
```

Indices matrix:

```
I = array([2, 0, 3, 2, 1])
```

`A` matrix:

```
A = array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]],

       [[30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44]],

       [[45, 46, 47],
        [48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53],
        [54, 55, 56],
        [57, 58, 59]],

       [[60, 61, 62],
        [63, 64, 65],
        [66, 67, 68],
        [69, 70, 71],
        [72, 73, 74]]])
```

I try to improve my code avoiding the for loop in this way:

```
r = r_[0:len(I)]
ACopy[r, I, :] = A[r, I, :] + A[r, I + 1, :]
```

I noticed that the output matrices `ACopy` are different and I can't understand why. Any idea?

Thank you all!

**EDIT**: I'm computing a lot of matrices and I try with `np.array_equals(ACopy1,ACopy2)`, where `ACopy1` is the output of the first method and `ACopy2` the output of the second method. Sometimes the matrices are the same, but not everytime. The two methods output should be the same or are there any bordeline case?

**EDIT2**: I noticed that this strange behaviour happens only when **matrix height is bigger than 256**.
Here is my test suite:

```
from numpy import *

w = 5
h = 257

for i in xrange(1000):
  Z = random.rand(w, h, 5)

  I = (random.rand(w) * h - 1).astype(uint8)
  r = r_[0:w]
  ZCopy = zeros(Z.shape)
  ZCopy2 = zeros(Z.shape)

  for j in xrange(0, size(Z, 0)):
    i = I[j]
    ZCopy[j, i, :] = Z[j, i, :] + Z[j, i + 1, :]

  ZCopy2[r, I, :] = Z[r, I, :] + Z[r, I + 1, :]

  if (ZCopy - ZCopy2).any() > 0:
    print(ZCopy, ZCopy2, I)
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Both codes produce the same outcome for me, but I do use a newer version of Numpy

Comment: Note that `I` must be Numpy array for this to work.

Comment: Please show us some small example input for which the new and old methods differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the problem! 
I cast the matrix **I** to **uint8** and so matrix **I** elements are between 0 and 255.
I resolved using `I = (random.rand(w) * h - 1).astype(uint32)`